# How to read DICOM file on android os?

Tags: android, dicom

I want to know how to display a DICOM file on the Android OS ? Can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some are using DCMTK (http://www.dcmtk.org) on Android via Android NDK to acces DICOM. There's a discussion about it on the DCMTK forums here: http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?t=2960&sid=868791a13b4d266998284b921c4bfe8c

Answer (score 1):

[Imebra](http://imebra.com/) now includes JNI wrappers for Android and comes with a pre-built jar that includes java classes and so libraries with native code.

Comment: Does Imebra have support for lower SDK versions like 22 (Android 5.1)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the Pixelmed Java DICOM Toolkit on Android, http://www.pixelmed.com . You should be able to use some of its functionality without even recompiling the JAR.